# Run Migration on synced Realm

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've created a new object model and when I open my app I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid class subset list:
- 'Mod.generalSettings' links to class 'Setting', which is missing from the list of classes managed by the Realm
- 'Mod.contextSettings' links to class 'Setting', which is missing from the list of classes managed by the Realm
- 'Mod.accountSettings' links to class 'Setting', which is missing from the list of classes managed by the Realm'
```

I don't get this error when I shut down the Realm Object Server that holds my synced Realm. This is the config that runs on launch:

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        syncConfiguration: (user, syncServerURL!),
        objectTypes: [Dot.self, Mod.self, Setting.self])
```

This leads me to believe I need to run a migration for my remote realm. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have direct access to Realm files on the server from the client. All you need to do is run a migration locally and the changes will be pushed up to the server.

If you're not deleting any columns, you can run a migration as simply as:

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        syncConfiguration: (user, syncServerURL!),
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in },
        objectTypes: [Dot.self, Mod.self, Setting.self])
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error ```Assertion failed: rlmSchema.objectSchema.count == schema.size()``` Full stack trace: http://imgur.com/a/6rgUh

Comment: Logging out the user and logging back in throws the same error as before "Invalid class subset list"